# How to limit the number of post values on UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have notice that the **UpdatePanel post every field included on the form** on every trigger.

But in most of my cases I use 2-3 UpdatePanels at the same page, and each one is independent.

When I click for update the one panel, then my page receive all the input data of the page (ok this is logical) but I won to read only this UpdatePanels data and act according, and not the other panels data.

So I see that a lot of traffic is happened this way.

So is there a way **to say to one UpdatePanel - send only my input data**, and not everything found on the page. ?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this isn't possible. Although UpdatePanel updates only a portion of the page, a full post-back is always happening. This is why an UpdatePanel isn't recommended for Ajax applications. You may consider using an Ajax client library, like jQuery and ajax-enabled WCF services. This will be much more efficient than UpdatePanels.

You can read a nice article about UpdatePanel [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx).

Comment: Yes this is also my conclusion... I just wondering maybe if some one have made any trick with javascript... or any new future on dot net 4.

Comment: No luck with javascript, UpdatePanel is a client and server technology. Not sure about .NET 4 also. UpdatePanel was designed to easily add Ajax functionality in an existing application. It isn't recommended for new projects.